# 3D player and 2D floor. I have collider problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I have problem with this object's collider. Cannot find 3D collider for this floor. I cannot use 2D collider because my player is 3D player. When i put 2D collider, my player is falling. What should i do for it ?

[image]

I created half triangle and made it mesh collider. But it did not be succestful.

Comment: Just use a box collider, or mesh collider (more cost but for something that simple it should be fine)

Comment: I'm lookıng 3D collider for ramp. Can i turn the box collider into half triangle? Because when i put box collider it does not work so well.

Comment: You could add a child to your triangle, rotate it 45° and add the collider to it, so it would fit your ramp. But again, for something that simple, you can use a mesh colider (check Convex)

Comment: `Collider2D` don't interact with `Collider`(3D) ... the Physics2D and Physics engine are completely separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture it looks like you're making a game with 2D perspective.

If you're making a 2D game it doesn't matter if the player uses a 3D model, it can still use 2D physics since you're not using the 3rd dimension.

My advice would be to change all the colliders to 2D colliders and use a [Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html) component for the slope (triangle) object. This should adjust the collider shape to your sprite.